# ReactJS Show Component Once Data in State is not Null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**EDIT:** So I was having some troubles with stack overflow and had to retype some things.... including Weather weatherData={this.state.weatherData} which I accidentally typed incorrectly on here as Weather weatherData={weatherData}. But I did also make a typing mistake on my code and that was with setState. I am new to reactjs and some of the syntax I find weird so that's probably why I have syntax errors. So I ended up fixing things, but was still having an error "this.setState is not a function". I figured maybe it was a scope problem so I made a new method updateWeatherData, and voila that worked.

So I am trying to make a weather app. What I want to do is load the child component called Weather once there is data in this.state.weatherData. I have checked with a console.log and the data is coming back from the ajax call but I can't seem to set it. The error message I am getting is "Cannot read property 'weatherData' of undefined"

```
var React = require('react');
var Weather = require('./Weather');


class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            weatherData: null,
        };
        this.getDataFromLatLng = this.getDataFromLatLng.bind(this);
        this.showPosition = this.showPosition.bind(this);
    }
    updateWeatherData (results)
    {
        this.setState({
            weatherData:results
        });
    }
    componentDidMount()
    {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition);

        } else {
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
    }
    showPosition(position)
    {
        this.getDataFromLatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    }
    getDataFromLatLng(lat, lng)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+lat+'&lon='+lng+"&units=metric&appid=ID",
            type:"GET",
            dataType:"jsonp",
             //CHANGED FROM THIS:
            /*success:function(results){
                //RESULTS COME BACK
                console.log(results);
                this.setState=({
                    weatherData:results
                });
                console.log(this.state.weatherData);
                //But no weatherData is being set

            },*/
            //TO THIS:
            success:this.updateWeatherData,
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              console.log(xhr.responseText + " " + status, " " + error);
            }
        });
    }
    render()
    {
        return(
            <div id="container">
                Hello From App
                {this.state.weatherData != null
                    ? <Weather weatherData={this.state.weatherData}/>
                    : <p>Loading...</p>
                }

            </div>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = App;
```

Comment: please show  console.log(results); and should be `<Weather weatherData={this.state.weatherData}/>`

Comment: You won't be able to see the changed state just after you changed it. That's the reason no value in `console.log(this.state.weatherData)`. Change `weatherData={weatherData}` to `weatherData={this.state.weatherData}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `<Weather weatherData={weatherData}/>` to `<Weather weatherData={this.state.weatherData}/>`

Regarding why `console.log(this.state.weatherData)` does not show the value that you have set, it is because `setState` is asynchronous. See [this article](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b).

Specifically, I am referring to the following lines from the article:

```
// assuming this.state = { value: 0 }
this.setState({
  value: 1
});
console.log(this.state.value); // 0
```

Comment: `Regarding why console.log(this.state.weatherData) does not show the value that you have set, it is because setState is asynchronous`  this is non-sense answer regarding this question.

Comment: Well, I am not so sure :) I will add few lines to further explain this...

Comment: Everybody doesn't know basic concepts. No need to write that this way...

Comment: that's the problem )))

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div id="container">
            Hello From App
            {this.state.weatherData != null
                ? <Weather weatherData={weatherData}/>
                : <p>Loading...</p>
            }

        </div>
```

here if you see your code , you want to it to render once this.state.weatherData has something in it. so lets say it has and now it is time to render.. Component you are rendering are being given props as weatherData ... but u didnt define it anywhere. you actually want to pass the state which would be

```
 <div id="container">
            Hello From App
            {this.state.weatherData != null
                ? <Weather weatherData={this.state.weatherData}/>
                : <p>Loading...</p>
            }

        </div>
```

and for the reason you can not see it because

```
  //RESULTS COME BACK
            console.log(results);


            this.setState=({
                weatherData:results
            });
            console.log(this.state.weatherData);
            //But no weatherData is being set
```

the results come and you setState the results. however this isnt an object you can set value to.. it will be called and react will do its thing and update the state but it doesn't do it before moving ahead. it just moves ahead and does it in the background asynchronously . once  getDataFromLatLng will get completed , the render will be called and you should always check for the updated state in the render method..

```
render(){
   console.log(this.state.weatherData);
   // Your Code here
}
```

you will see the updated state there.
as for where you are passing props as weatherData instead of this.state.weatherData , if you are going to use it more in render like you are using twice. you can if you like use it like this. this is called [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

```
render(){
  const {weatherData} = this.state ;
 return(
        <div id="container">
            Hello From App
            {weatherData != null
                ? <Weather weatherData={weatherData}/>
                : <p>Loading...</p>
            }

        </div>
    );
}
```

you can use weatherData now instead of this.state.weatherData. we use const here to declare because state is immutable so you dont by mistake mutate it in render.